# Constraints Issues On UI button

Tags: ios, autolayout

While practicing programmatic constraints using anchors  ,I came across a problem that hides the visibility of the button when using an iPhone 8 or 8 plus simulator as shown in the image below. This is due to the current coordinate values I set for the button. However the button becomes visible when I switch to an iPhone 12. How do I set the co-ordinate values in a way that makes the button visible and in same positions on the  iPhone 8 or 8 plus ?
[image: Iphone12]

```
let iosImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-ios-logo-128"))
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageview
    }()
    
    let press: UIButton = {
        let buttonPress = UIButton.init(type: .roundedRect)
        buttonPress.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        buttonPress.backgroundColor = .black
        buttonPress.frame = CGRect(x: 110, y: 700, width: 200, height: 50)

        return buttonPress
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSubviews()
        setConstraints()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func addSubviews(){
        view.addSubview(iosImageView)
        view.addSubview(press)
    }
    
    func setConstraints(){
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iosImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            iosImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            iosImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  200),
            iosImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
           
            press.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            press.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            press.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)

        ])
    }
```

[image: iPhone 8]

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints for `press` are invalid. You failed to specify a vertical position. And you forgot to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be false. I’m surprised the button ever appears.

(Also cut the line about `buttonPress.frame`. Frame and constraints are opposites; use one or the other.)

Comment: How can improve setting constraints programmaticallly ?

Comment: I think my answer has answered that.

Comment: I know you did I wasn't referring to it. I am struggling with the use of anchors and its very difficult. How can I improve ?

Comment: That's not a programming matter. There are many autolayout tutorials and books but that is not a Stack Overflow subject. I believe I've answered the question.